# service: not found optware on dd-wrt

Tags: dd-wrt

i have just installed optware package on dd-wrt.

when i execute service command, it cannot be found.

What is wrong?

screenshot is attached.

**---- EDIT -----**
my router is asus wl-520gu

[image]

Comment: Perhaps some info how exactly did you install the software? And what you think should be expected output of commands run...

Answer (score 0):

I've never run dd-wrt, but if it's linux based, service is probably in `/sbin`.  What happens when you try `/sbin/service`? If that works, you need to add `/sbin` to your `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

service should just run directly upon login (just tested it myself) - that is, it is your path.

If it isn't in your path, it should be in /opt/usr/sbin

You might want to [Optware, the Right Way](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Optware,_the_Right_Way) for the install (your screenshot suggests that you haven't used their install script).